# how to extract the "after_insert" from db.event.listens_for(Order, "after_insert")

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

i am planning to stack a couple of decorators on a function and depending on the operation i an if statement in the function to run.

```
@db.event.listens_for(Order, "after_delete")
@db.event.listens_for(Order, "after_insert")
def order_after_delete(mapper, connection, target):
    # find if it was triggered by 'after_delete' or 'after_insert'
    # do stuff...
    if something=='after_insert':
        print('after_insert')
    elif something=='after_delete':
        print('after_insert')
```

is there a way to get that information from one of the `(mapper, connection, target)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect target. Inserted object has no an identity key.

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect

@db.event.listens_for(Order, "after_delete")
@db.event.listens_for(Order, "after_insert")
def order_after_delete(mapper, connection, target):
    insp = inspect(target)
    if not insp.has_identity:
        print('after_insert')
    else:
        print('after_delete')
```